# Rviz and Nodelets

Tags: ros, rviz, mesh, 3d-visualization, nodelets

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to use nodelets that would allow drawing objects in Rviz without having to send messages/copy data? I would like to visualize a large triangle mesh that gets updated periodically (probably ~1 Hz) and don't want to have to send out a message/waste time copying data.

My understanding is that this is the primary motivation for nodelets, but I'm not sure if it would be possible to tack on my potential mesh nodelet onto the main Rviz process.

Any ideas? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213951/rviz-and-nodelets/) by [wng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2471/wng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2015-07-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately there is no nodelet for rviz at the moment. It may be possible to implement such a thing, but I'm not aware of anyone who has done this. If you're planning on trying to do something like this, you could ask ros-users to see if others have already done this or if others are interested in working on it with you.

`rqt_rviz` might be a starting point for for figuring out how to start an instance of rviz in your own C++ program:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_robot_plugins/blob/hydro-devel/rqt_rviz/src/rqt_rviz/rviz.cpp

Though there are some known issues when using `rqt_rviz` in conjunction with other C++ rqt nodes in the same process, but I'm sure if that would be an issue for you was well.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1